Measuring effects of factors on a DV that has multiple zeros?
I have several thousand distance measurements for fish in two ponds across two trials (different fish in each trial) exposed to three treatments (control, food exposure, sound exposure). I want to know what the impact of treatment, trial, ID, and pond are on my distance measurements. I am using R. Initially, I ran a linear mixed effects model as such:
fit1 = lmer(step_m ~ treatment + (1|ID) + (1|trial) + (1|pond), data=df)

Output:
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: step_m ~ treatment + (1 | period) + (1 | trial) + (1 | pond)
   Data: tptr_sf_txonly_noNA_censored
REML criterion at convergence: -23116.18
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev. 
 period   (Intercept) 7.857e-02
 trial    (Intercept) 4.670e-06
 pond     (Intercept) 2.301e-02
 Residual             2.048e-01
Number of obs: 70196, groups:  period, 54; trial, 2; pond, 2
Fixed Effects:
   (Intercept)   treatmentFeed  treatmentSound  
       0.15197         0.06658         0.05381  
optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK) ; 0 optimizer warnings; 1 lme4 warnings 

From this, I gather that the effect of trial is very small, perhaps negligible. I'm not concerned with formal statistical comparison, I just want an idea of the contribution of each factor.
That being said, my DV violates most of the assumptions of a linear model
Is it still appropriate for me to evaluate my data this way or should I be looking at other methods? I've looked into transforming the data, but since I have a lot of 0s in the data, the only transformation that looks decent is a two-parameter boxcox transformation, but even so, it's not quite normal:
Original data density plot:

Original data plots of residuals
2-parameter boxcox transformed:

2-parameter boxcox transformed residuals

Any thoughts on the least complicated way to proceed would be much appreciated! Again, I just want to find a good way to look at how much these factors are contributing to my DV.

I think you might have the random effects specified incorrectly. It sounds like fish are nested in ponds but that trials may be crossed with ponds. See if this question and answer helps. That won’t help the distribution issues but you’ll need to sort that out too. Remember though, it’s the residuals that matter, so Box-Cox should be fine.

Why would you want to transform the distances? Any conclusion from a significant test on the transformed values can not be back-infered to the original data. Imagine a simple 1-sample t-test on a well behaved (~normal) sample; on the original data the test is not significant. But if I square the values (a common transformation), the result may well become significant. What can I conclude about the mean of my original sample?

@RickHass thank you for pointing that out. So my understanding is that it should look like:
fit1 = lmer(step_m ~ treatment + (1|pond/ID) + (1|trial), data=df)?

Perhaps. Admittedly, I'm not an expert in the mixing of crossed and nested designs. I stick with nested as it's easier ;)
